# Is there a jQuery or CSS slider with a scroll effect similar to this one?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

Does anyone know a jquery or css slider with a horizontal scroll effect like the one in https://elizabethtaylor.com?

I would like to achieve an effect similar to the one on the content hovering the background of each slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the script I was looking for. The solution is [Sequence.js](https://www.sequencejs.com/). It's a slider that uses javascript to assign classes to the content inside the slides whilst they're sliding in or out. Combining this classes with CSS animations it's possible to have a slider with complex effects.

Just modifying some CSS lines from the basic example theme, you can have a slider similar to the one showed in https://elizabethtaylor.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery slick slider

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I can get the horizontal scroll with that slider, but I don't know how I could achieve the delayed animation on the content hovering the slide.